# Trigger on opportunity object

Tags: trigger

There is one object let say Account. In Account I have  field called Amount1  Now when I enter value in Amount1 at the time of creation of account record. Account1 field value get updated as'********' , that I am doing by after Insert event.

so for this case I have to go by after insert event. I am doing the same by after insert event but it throws an error 'Field is read only'.

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account(after insert)
{
 for(Account currAcc: Trigger.new)
 {
     if(currAcc.Amount1__c != null)
     {
        currAcc.Amount1__c = '**********';

     }      
 }
}
```

Comment: Why you need after insert. You should do this in before insert.

Comment: If you want to pre-populate something on Account at the time of insertion then you should use `before insert` event. You can not modify fields in `after insert` event, as they are partially saved in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After save record you cannot update same object. you have to use before insert on same object.

> Note : After Insert/Update/Delete/Undelete event on cross object.

```
  trigger AccountTrigger on Account(before insert){
   for(Account currAcc: Trigger.new){
      if(currAcc.Amount1__c != null){
           currAcc.Amount1__c = '**********';

       }      
   }
  }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your valuable reply's EACH AND EVERYONE

Comment: I HAVE TO USE AFTER INSERT AND DO THE TASK, IS THERE ANY OTHER WAY TO DO THAT ABOVE REQUIREMENT USING AFTER INSERT

Comment: ANYWAYS YOUR TRIGGER IS WORKING @cloudZigZag